# Out of Memory while using curl with php

Tags: php, curl, out-of-memory, fatal-error

I am fetching products from flipkart's affiliation API.
But after going through lots of its json I am getting following error.

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 223084544) (tried to allocate 65488 bytes)
```

My code is

```
$ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt(
        $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
        array(
            "Fk-Affiliate-Id:$Affliate_ID",
            "Fk-Affiliate-Token:$Token",
            "Accept:application/json"
        )
    );

    // Disable SSL verification
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    // Will return the response, if false it print the response
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Set the url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$endpoint);

    // Execute
    $result=curl_exec($ch);

    // Closing
    curl_close($ch);
```

Even I tried define function and increased the memory to 512B but still I am getting the same issue.

Comment: "and increased the memory to 512B" --- you have not. `223084544` is not 512MB.

Comment: before increasing also it was giving the same error and I read about define in stack it self

Comment: You have not increased it. The amount of available memory is far from 512MB